# PlayN Camera and Input support

Tags: camera, playn

We wan't to implement a game for ios, android and html5.

We appreciate the playN-project a lot. But we are not sure whether our features are covered by playN.
Especially the following:

- text input (username and a short statement)
- capturing QR-Codes by camera (reading and processing QR-code)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Right now,there is a mostly working implementation of text input via [TriplePlay](https://github.com/threerings/tripleplay), but there is not camera support yet.